# package javax.mail does not exist for centos 6.2

Tags: java, centos

I have a centos 6.2 server. I have put the mail.jar into /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext folder. Then when I compile my java it gives me this error. The funny part I have done this last month on another server also with centos 6.2 and same java version all works fine. What could be missing here?

```
package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.Message;
```

Comment: Why do you mess with the JDK install in the first place? Why don't you simply put the jar in the classpath when building and running your app?

Comment: also do you still need mail.jar in the classpath ?

Comment: So we are not suppose to put there is it? But why it have been working over year will all my other server except for this. I even google and some say is ok to put there. Ok now I have compile this like this java -classpath /usr/local/cs9000/lib cs9000.java. I could compile with no complain but when I try to run it gives me another error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jolbox/bonecp/BoneCPConfig
I have put all .jar which I have used in the /usr/local/cs9000/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your program is using the java in that jdk you put the mail.jar file in. This type of setup only works if you are using java.exe from the path you put the jar in. It's harder to maintain this because you have to remember to copy that jar if you ever update the jdk. You really just need to make sure mail.jar is in the classpath of the class that needs it. If you jar it up with your program then you just add it to the classpath in your manifest file in the jar. If you do not use a jar, another option is passing it in on the command line.

Ex. java -classpath=c:\temp\mail.jar myclass

Comment: Ok now I have compile this like this java -classpath /usr/local/cs9000/lib cs9000.java. I could compile with no complain but when I try to run it gives me another error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jolbox/bonecp/BoneCPConfig I have put all .jar which I have used in the /usr/local/cs9000/lib. So what should I do next ?

Comment: Add the current directory to the classpath. After cs9000/lib;. The ;. Adds the current directory to the classpath. Sometimes its: depending on your OS.

Comment: Actually what is this classpath is to define the .jar location is it? Why it works for all my other machines even the same os? Ok I manage to run it like this java -classpath .:/usr/local/cs9000/lib cs9000. IS this the right method now?